# How To Create Year View Layout in Android Application

Tags: android, layout

I want to create year layout in calendar like this.

[image: Samsung Calendar Year view]

I was thinking using 12 multiple gridviews in one big gridview but it seems impossible.
Can you give me a suggestion or example?

Comment: you want to do exactly like this..?

Comment: yes. i want the same layout like this

Comment: okk.. then i think you can use gridview or tablelayout

Comment: can you be more specific or give me an example? thanks

Comment: i have no example but what you thinking is right you need 12 griedview and one big gridview

Comment: that's not working and it's the reason i ask here